# Prove $\frac {uv} {(u+v)^2}$ is real and $\frac {u+v}{u-v}$ imaginary when $|u| = |v| = 1$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, complex-numbers, contest-math

Let $u,v \in \mathbb C, u\ne\pm v, |u| = |v| = 1$.  Show $$ \frac {uv}{(u+v)^2} \in \mathbb R, \quad \frac {u+v}{u-v}i \in \mathbb R.$$  *Source: Art of Problem Solving.*

My proof is below.  I request verification and critique on both the proofs and exposition as well as other approaches.

---

**Proof 1:** Since $u\bar u = 1 = v \bar v$, then $$uv(\bar u + \bar v)^2 = u \bar v + v \bar u + 2 = \bar u \bar v (u + v)^2$$ then $$\frac {uv} {(u + v)^2} = \overline{\frac{uv}{(u+v)^2}}$$ and is real.  Likewise, since $$(u+v)(\bar u - \bar v) = v \bar u - u \bar v = -(u-v)(\bar u + \bar v)$$ then $$\frac {u+v}{u-v} = -\overline{\frac{u+v}{u-v}}$$ and is pure imaginary.

**Proof 2:** Let $w = u+v$.  Quadrilateral $O,U,V,W$ is a parallelogram with $OU \cong OV$ and therefore a rhombus.  Therefore, its diagonal $OW$ bisects $\angle UOV$.  Then $$\arg(u+ v)= \arg w  = \frac 1 2 (\arg u + \arg v) = \frac 1 2 \arg(uv)$$ and $$\arg (u+v)^2 = \arg(uv).$$  Consequently, their ratio $\frac {uv}{(u+v)^2}$ is real.

Likewise, $u+v$ and $u-v$ are diagonals of this rhombus and consequently mutually perpendicular.  Their ratio is therefore pure imaginary, completing the proof.

Comment: Let $w=u/v.$ Then $|w|=1.$ The first expression is the reciprocal of ${w}+\overline{w}+2.$ The second expression can be represented as ${1+w\over 1-\overline{w}}i $

Comment: Another method : write $u=e^{ix}$ and $v=e^{iy}$ ;
and note that

$$e^{ix}+e^{iy}=e^{i\frac{x+y}{2}}\left(e^{i\frac{x-y}{2}}+e^{-i\frac{x-y}{2}}\right)=2e^{i\frac{x+y}{2}}\cos{\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: Probably minor, but did you mean to write $\arg(u+v)$ instead of $\arg u + v$ in Proof 2?

Comment: $(u^2+v^2+2uv)/uv=w+w^{-1}+2$ and $w^{-1}=\overline{w},$ because $w\overline{w}=|w|^2=1.$

Comment: $$\frac{uv}{(u+v)^2}=\frac1{|u+v|^2}\in\Bbb R\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{u+v}{u-v}=\frac{v\bar u-u\bar v}{|u-v|^2}\in i\Bbb R.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw on argand plane. $u$ and $v$ lies on the unit circle centered on the origin. $u-v$ is parallel to the secant line passing through $u$ and $v$. $u+v$ is parallel to line passing through the origin and the midpoint of $uv$. Consequently, $u+v\perp u-v$ or

$$
\frac{u-v}{u+v}\in \mathbb{I}
$$

For the second part,

$$
\frac{uv}{(u+v)^{2}}
=
\frac{1}{4}\left(
1 + \left(
\frac{u-v}{u+v}
\right)^{2}
\right)
$$

Square of pure imaginary number is real, proven.